# Define ATL Interface method which create another interface pointer?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I am creating Oracle data access com library in ATL. There exist a COM interface named IConnection which perform database connection. I would like to add method to IConnection called CreateCommand to create object of type IOciCommand. IOciCommand already an Interface in the same library. I need IDL code and the implementation of CreateCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you the exact implementation of CreateCommand because I don't know the internals of your library, but the basic steps are:

(1) Add the method to the IDL interface:

```
interface IConnection : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT CreateCommand([out] IOciCommand** ppCommand);
}
```

(2) Compile the IDL file.

(3) Add the method implementation to the C++ class that implements the interface:

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateCommand(IOciCommand** ppCommand)
{
    if (ppCommand == NULL)
        return E_POINTER;

    CComObject<COciCommand>* pCommand;
    HRESULT hr = CComObject<COciCommand>::CreateInstance(&pCommand);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    *ppCommand = pCommand;
    (*ppCommand)->AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}
```

That's how the implementation will look basically, but it's obviously over-simplified.